# gazebo collision detection

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugin, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am looking to perform collision detection between specific links in a model both internally (e.g. link 1 to link 2 of model 1) and externally (e.g. link 1 of model 1 to any part of model 2). My initial intention was to write a gazebo model/world plugin to assess the collisions of the links and perform actions (i.e. apply joint torques) accordingly; however, I can't find a way to access the collision elements. Suggestions? (Note, this is similiar to the post http://answers.ros.org/question/39054/getting-collisions-in-gazebo-plugin/)

I've tried using the gazebo_ros_bumper as suggested in the post referenced above, but always see the state returning [] and an error message: "Contact sensor[link_name_contact_sensor] has no collsion[link_name_geom]" Otherwise, there are no error messages while setting up the bumper.

I'm running the current version of fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43368/gazebo-collision-detection/) by [rjmurphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3163/rjmurphy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just fixed it, see http://answers.ros.org/question/41765/contactsensor-in-gazebofuerte

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0